# Stomp and Temporary queues

Tags: stomp

I have a script that sends a message to a subscriber on a well known queue.  It then waits for a reply on a temporary queue.  If no reply comes within 10 seconds, the script errors out and terminates.  I understand that this will destroy the temporary queue, however the messages (if for example the subscriber is not up at the time the message was sent) will remain on the well known queue, and when the subscriber comes up it will read the old messages and reply to the temporary queue.  This is all in python using stompy.  I'm assuming that the temporary queue will be re-instantiated when the reply is made.  So the question is how can I check if the temp queue still exists in the broker before doing the reply.  I'm using Apollo as the message broker.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of experimentation,  if the message is sent back on the temp queue, it shows up in the apollo broker for a short period and then gets dropped.  So i guess i answered my own question